# Redux state returns undefined after an update

Tags: javascript, redux

I ma having a simple reducers state that was working fine. M reducer is below.

```
const initialState  =
{
plan: [
    {
       id: 0,
       text: 'Submit math assignment at noon.',
       completed: false
    }
]
}
function mytodo(state = initialState, type) {
    switch(type) {
        ...
        default: 
            return state;    
    }
}
```

My app works fine. Then concat some localstorage data to my state. My state now returns undefined.

```
const storageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('plan'));

 function mytodo(state = initialState, type) {
        switch(type) {
            ...
            default: 
                console.log('the storage data is', storageItems);
                return storageItems ? state.plan.concat(storageItems) : state;    
        }
    }
```

I confirmed the storage items above has data yet my reducer returned undefined as plan to my component. I then changed this to.

```
const storageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('plan'));
if(storageItems) {
    initialState = initialState.todos.concat(storageItems);
    console.log('the states are', initialState);
}

function mytodo(state = initialState, type) {
        switch(type) {
            ...
            default: 
                return state;    
        }
    }
```

and change initialState to let. Still it returns undefined. Initial state from the console above returns the complete result i needed. However, it does not return the value to my component provided i update the initialState. Please what am i doing wrong? How do i addressed this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.concat()` returns a new array object https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat . Check where the error is thrown. The object may not be empty but the order might have been changed.

```
const initialState  =
{
plan: [
    {
       id: 0,
       text: 'Submit math assignment at noon.',
       completed: false
    }
]
}
```

From the above, initialState.plan should return your plan array.

However,

```
initialState = initialState.todos.concat(storageItems);
```

Would return new array. Now your initialState would take the form

```
initialState = [{
           id: 0,
           text: 'Submit math assignment at noon.',
           completed: false
        }]
```

Therefore if you have your `state.plan` anywhere would throw an undefined error because your state have changed. Hope here about concat https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat